# Connecting untrained python predictive model to backend

Tags: python, deployment, artificial-intelligence, prediction

I already have a built predictive model written in Python, however currently it is executed by hand and functions on a single data file. I am hoping to generalize the model so that it can read in different datasets from my backend, each time effectively producing a different model since we are using different data for training as well. How would I be able to add the model onto my backend then?

Answer (score 0):

Store the model as a pickle and read it from your backend when you need analog to your training data.

But you might want to checkout [MLFlow](https://mlflow.org/) for an integrated model handling solution. It is possible to run it on prem. With MLFlow you can easily implement a proper ML lifecycle. You can store your training stats and keep the history of your trained models.